# Applying Maven Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Great to have the Maven Gradle Plugin, but the documentation could be a lot better.  What I want to know is how to invoke the whole gradle script below  from within Maven plugin:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.fortasoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>gradle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                <!-- this would effectively call "gradle doSomething" -->
                <task>doSomething</task>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                 <!-- You can bind this to any phase you like -->
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                 <!-- goal must be "invoke" -->
                        <goal>invoke</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>
    </plugin>
```

So the doSomething I above, I want to be the outer task of gradle?  In other words just execute the whole darn script?  How would also use it to do gradle clean? how about doing

```
  gradle clean build
```

Would I need one task after the other in order?  Does the plugin support several tasks in order? its not clear to me.

```
 import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*

 buildscript {
     repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.8.11'
   }
 }

     def getSvnRevision(){
        ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
       SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
        SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
        SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
       SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
       return revision.getNumber();
    }

    allprojects {
        version = '1.2.3.' + getSvnRevision()
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://mysnaps:8084/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
}


 android {
  lintOptions {
       abortOnError false
   }

   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.myapps.app"
      minSdkVersion 8
       targetSdkVersion 17
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
 }

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'alibs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mycom:mycom-comp:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
 }  

  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-  ${variant.versionName}."+ getSvnRevision() + ".apk"))
     }


  }
// Move the build types to build-types/<type>
// For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-  types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
// This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/...   which would
// conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
// Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
// by a similar customization.



 }

  task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6'
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Simply run gradle, and use maven gradle pluging for invoking simple tasks, not whole gradle build.

Comment: Ok, how exactly would I run command to clean and build?

Comment: gradle build is not simple task. Why do you want to wrap whole gradle build into maven?